# How to use mongodb aggregate functions in Criteria?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I am working on a project where I use spring data mongodb. I am making a mongo query like this:

```
Query query = new Query();

Criteria one = Criteria.where(DB_FIELD_1).gt(1);
Criteria two = Criteria.where(DB_FIELD_2).lt(10);

Criteria final = new Criteria().andOperator(one,two);
query.addCriteria(final);

// after making the query, I am executing it using mongoTemplate
```

Now, I have a Date field with format YYYYMMDD. I would like to check if its month = current month. For example, if the field is 20170501, then the date's month (05) is current month (5, May). How do I extract the month value from date and check this logic along with other criteria above ( one and two )? I know there is $month to extract the month value from date. But, I do not know how to incorporate aggregate function within "Criteria" class. My final result should be something like this:

```
 Criteria final = new Criteria().andOperator(one,two,criteria to check month = current month);
 query.addCriteria(final);
```

Comment: date field is stored as String in DB?

Comment: its stored as Date

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection to the post ? and what is your spring mongo db version ? You will need to use projection expression for this one.

Comment: spring mogo db version is 1.4.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation pipeline with the current spring db version 1.10.2/ Spring 1.5.2 Boot. Include the other fields in the `$project` that you wish to output.

Use `$addFields` instead of `$project` for 3.4 x mongo server version.

```
 AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().and(DateOperators.dateOf(DB_FIELD_1).month()).as("field1").and(DateOperators.dateOf(DB_FIELD_2).month()).as("field2");
 AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("field1").gt(1)
                .and("field2").lt(10));
 Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, match);
 List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionname, BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Use for 1.4.1 version

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().and(DB_FIELD_1).extractMonth().as("field1").and(DB_FIELD_2).extractMonth().as("field2");
```

Comment: what is project() in the first line?

Comment: Sorry, it is to create `$project` stage. Use `Aggregation.project()`. Updated answer.

Comment: and also, DateOperators. I cant find that class

Comment: Okay Can you update to 1.5.2 boot version ? Btw added 1.4.1 update